# STM32F769 Change/Update IP Address Issue

Tags: stm32

I have a problem. I am working on STM32F769 TCP/IP ethernet protocol. I can send data to arm and send data back to pc / terminal . Problem is that I don't know which function or functions need to change IP address of device. I can get 4 byte data when user send.
Thanks.

Comment: well, you don't tell us which TCP/IP software stack you're using – there's many that run on ARM cortex-M processors. That network stack has a way of defining the IP address of itself.

You'll have to read the documentation of your TCP/IP stack to figure out how that is done.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Stm32CubeMX LWIP MiddleWare . In LWIP configuration , any IP ADDRESS can be assigned by disabling LWIP_DHCP, I know it . But after generating code, I have to update IP, SetMask and GateWay  address when user requires. But I don't know how to change.

Comment: Please add that info to your question!

Comment: Hi Marcus, I solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Can we know the solution as well?

Comment: My problem was all about compiling error . If you add input parameter LWIP_init(void) function in lwip.c , you can update IP address, Netmask or Gateway address. for example if you change that function as  LWIP_Init(int IPAddress[0],  IPAddress[1], IPAddress[2], IPAddress[3]) then IP address will be updated. Also you can use just netif_set_addr function in netif.c, it works.

Comment: Hello, I have a question now. When I use netif_set_addr function to change IP Address , that's ok . But in my project , I need to use the initial ip just one time( CubeMX sets  an initial  Ip address  by using LWIP_init function), then I have to change with data that users send. I can save data to flash . And after power off - power on system , system must  connect  new Ip address which read from flash memory . How to do it ? Do you have any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: I need to use the inital adress just one time then every power on system, it have to connect with new ip data (4 bytes) reads from flash.

Comment: I solved my problem. Thanks for your help !